React-native as iOS static framework - fails to find exposed classes in hosting iOS project
I have a react-native project that I need to export as static framework, which needs to be embedded into native iOS project.
After a lot of troubles I was able to build the target for framework and made sure hosting app recognizes the framework. However, I can not use exposed view in the hosting app as the hosting app does not recognize the class.
Code:
//  ReactNativeViewManager.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@interface ReactNativeViewManager : NSObject
+ (RCTRootView *)createReactNativeRootView;
+ (NSURL *)bundleURL;
@end

Main class:
#import "ReactNativeViewManager.h"

@implementation ReactNativeViewManager

+ (RCTRootView *)createReactNativeRootView {
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [self bundleURL];
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleProvider:nil launchOptions:nil];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"reactNativeApp" initialProperties:nil];
  return rootView;
}

+ (NSURL *)bundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end

I have added the header to Build Phases > Headers as public, which results in the header file present in framework folder. I import the my framework in the ViewController and the import doesn't complain. Meaning it recognizes the framework. But not the file.

